# React Navigation failing to render multi-HOC component in Jest Snapshot Testing

Tags: react-native, react-redux, jestjs, react-navigation

Simply put, I have a component that is composed from three Higher-Order Components. Two are custom made, the third is the connect HOC from redux. The component's export definition looks like this:

`const SplashPageContainer = compose(
  connect(mapStateToProps, null),
  withDrawer({label: 'Splash', title: 'Lynked App'}),
  withTabs()
)(SplashPage);`

There are no errors being thrown while running the app. In actuality, it runs correctly in development and production. However, inside my jest test suite, I get the following error:

```
The component for route 'Splash' must be a React component. For example:

import MyScreen from './MyScreen';
...
Splash: MyScreen,
}
```

After console.logging the return from 'Splash', I get:

```
{ [Function: Connect]
    WrappedComponent:
     { [Function: WithDrawerComponent]
       navigationOptions: [Function],
       defaultProps: { drawerOptions: [Object] },
       propTypes: { drawerOptions: [Object], navigation: [Object] } },
    displayName: 'Connect(WithDrawerComponent)',
    childContextTypes: { storeSubscription: { [Function: bound checkType] isRequired: [Function: bound checkType] } },
    contextTypes:
     { store: { [Function: bound checkType] isRequired: [Function: bound checkType] },
       storeSubscription: { [Function: bound checkType] isRequired: [Function: bound checkType] } },
    propTypes:
     { store: { [Function: bound checkType] isRequired: [Function: bound checkType] },
       storeSubscription: { [Function: bound checkType] isRequired: [Function: bound checkType] } },
    navigationOptions: [Function] }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: do you have any components inside your main component which needs the navigator prop? I get "Invariant Violation: withNavigation can only be used on a view hierarchy of a navigator. The wrapped component is unable to get access to navigation from props or context." error somewhere else, additionally.